# how to call dynamic URL key in product page?

Tags: product, url

I only know that getProductUrl() ?> is calling "http://b2b.com/product1/" But how to call a dynamic URL key in the /product/view.phtml, so then in the URL structure only the domain is changed from b2b.com to b2c.com but the product key will stay the same according to which product is being viewed?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Try rephrasing it or it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

If the site is setup with the proper store scopes, native magento will handle this for you through the

```
getProductUrl()
```

function.  You should confirm the base_url is set properly for both store scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work for you, but hopefully this will get you in the right direction.

To get the `URL key` you should use `$product->getUrlPath();` If the url is http:://b2b.com/product1 it will give you 'product1'

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution that is exactly what I want to achieve:

`<a href="http://google.com/<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()) ?><?php  echo $_product->getUrlKey(); ?>">ProductName</a>`

Then the URL link will be shown as google.com/ProductName